# How to pause a method till getting response from Rg.Plugins.Popup in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup for a simple confirmation popup before deleting an item from the list like "Are you sure you want to delete Item1 from the list?".
I need to know how to pause the deleting method till it gets the confirmation from the popup.

```
private async void MenuItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
            var item= menuItem.CommandParameter as Item;


            var page = new popupAlert(item);
            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);

           // Pause here
             myList.remove(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not leverage MessagingCenter to call a method which will remove said item ?

You could subscribe to the message when displaying the popup and receive it when the confirm button has been clicked.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)

**For example, create `PopupAlert` page with an async `Show` method:**

```
public class PopupAlert : PopupPage
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs = null;
    public PopupAlert()
    {
        var yesBtn = new Button { Text = "OK" };
        var noBtn = new Button { Text = "Cancel" };

        yesBtn.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync();
            _tcs?.SetResult(true);
        };
        noBtn.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync();
            _tcs?.SetResult(false);
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Padding = 20,
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Are you sure you want to delete?" },
                new StackLayout {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children = { yesBtn, noBtn }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public async Task<bool> Show()
    {
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(this);

        return await _tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

**And, usage would look like**

```
private async void MenuItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    var item = menuItem.CommandParameter as Item;

    var popupAlert = new PopupAlert();
    var result = await popup.Show(); //wait till user taps/selects option 

    if(result) //check for user selection here
        myList.remove(item);
}
```

Comment: I could just use the message center for it. Thanks for your solution , this will come handy in future implementations :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do same thing using existing xamarin control that is DisplayAlert.

```
var input= await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Delete Item", "Are You sure you  want to delete this Item?", "Yes","No");
if(input)
{
  myList.remove(item);
} 
else
{
  return;
}
```

In Above code if user press yes then function returns true and if no then false.

Comment: I needed to use a custom Alert for the sake of my App theme :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add Aziris Morora's answer, here is sample code (for reference)

```
//Main Page Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<userDetail>(this, "PopUpData", (value) =>
    {
        string receivedData = value.username;
        usernameLabel.text = receivedData;
    });

}



//PopUp Page Button clicked
private async void OnClickPopUpBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PopupNavigation.PopAsync(true);

    string name = username.Text.ToString();

    MessagingCenter.Send(new userDetail() { username = name }, "PopUpData");
}


//Model Class

class UserDetails
{
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```